# Spit the array such that gcd(val[i],val[j])>1

Tags: c++

It is good array only if *gcd(val[i],val[j])>1*

Here,

*gcd(a,b)* = Greatest common divisor of two numbers.

Split the array has one parameter

**Val**: A integer array of n integer

Here are two examples.

```
Sample Input 0:
5 // no of value in an integer
2
3
2
3
3
Sample Output 0:
2

Sample Input 1:
5   //no of value in an integer
3
5
7
11
2

Sample Output 1:
5
```

example of sample **input 0**

subarray[1..3] ={2,3,2}  here gcd(2,2)>1

subarray[4..5]={3,3}  gcd(3,3)>1

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

string ltrim(const string &);
string rtrim(const string &);
```

Now how to impelement the splitTheArray() function?

Comment: Is this a hackerank question??

Comment: yes can you help me @sha111

Comment: provide its link. to understand it..

Comment: @sha111 you can't access that

Comment: we have to split array such that , last and first value of sub-array's gcd must be greater than 1 ?? ( this is the question?? )

Comment: number of such sub array's..

Comment: subarray val[i t0 j ] is a good array such that only if gcd(val[i],val[j])>1

Comment: @sha111 yeah number of such sub array

Comment: val[i t0 j ] , what is t0

Comment: @sha111 can i send you a mail

Comment: @sha111 if possible pls

Comment: sure.you can.....

Comment: @sha111 did you get the mail its on your  github

Comment: mail it on "sha4adv1@gmail.com"

Comment: @faruk-hossain can you help me

Comment: Yeah of course. I have some confusion about this problem.
You have to split the array into minimum sub-arrays such that gcd of each sub-array is >1. Is it the summarise of this question?

Comment: @FarukHossain yes that's the problem

Comment: @FarukHossain ??

Comment: Check now. Does it work?

Comment: yes for 6 cases

Comment: Complexity of this algorithm is O(n ^2). You need to optimise it in O(n) or O(nlogn).

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the minimum number of subarrays such that in each sub-array, first and last elements' **gcd** **> 1**. You can do it easily by O(Nˆ2) complexity.

```
int splitTheArray(vector<int> val) {
 // implement this function
 int sz = val.size();
 if(sz == 0) return 0;
 int ind = sz - 1;
 int subarray = 0;
 while(ind >= 0) {
     for(int i = 0; i <= ind; i++) {
         if(__gcd(val[ind], val[i]) > 1) {
             subarray++;
             ind = i-1;
             break;
         }
     }
 }
 return subarray;
}
```

Comment: int subarray =0 ;

Comment: This is not correct. consider test case [ 10,13,17,9,23,6,6,29,3 ] and [ 3,29,6,6,23,9,17,13,10 ]

Answer (score 0):

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int gcd(int a, int b)
{
 if (b == 0)
  return a;
 return gcd(b, a % b);

}

int max(int a, int b)
{
 return (a > b) ? a : b;
}

int min(int a, int b)
{
 return (a < b) ? a : b;
}

int solve(vector<int> vec)
{
 int n = gcd(vec[0], vec[vec.size() - 1]);

 if (n > 1)
  return 0;

 int con = 0 , flag = 0 , j=0 , i=0 , flag2=0;

 for (i = j; i < vec.size()/2; i++)
 {
  i = j;

  if (i >= vec.size())
   break;

  int f = vec[i];

  flag = 0;

  for (j = i+1; j < vec.size(); j++)
  {
   int l = vec[j];

   int ma = max(f, l);
   int mi = min(f, l);

   n = gcd(ma, mi);

   if (flag)
   {
    if (n > 1)
     con++;
    else
     break;
   }

   if (n > 1)
   {
    flag = 1;
    flag2 = 1;
    con++;
   }
  }
 }

 if (!flag2)
  return vec.size();

 return con;
}

int main()
{
 int n;

 cin >> n;

 vector<int> vec;

 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
  int tm;

  cin >> tm;

  vec.emplace_back(tm);
 }

 cout<<solve(vec);

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define int long long int
#define boost ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);cin.tie(NULL);cout.tie(NULL)
void solve()
{
    int n,i,j;
    cin>>n;
    int A[n+1],DP[n+1];
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        cin>>A[i];
    memset(DP,0,sizeof(DP));
    unordered_map<int,int> M;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        vector<int> Fact;
        Fact.push_back(A[i]);
        for(j=2;j*j<=A[i];j++)
        {
            if(A[i]%j==0)
            {
                if(j*j==A[i])
                {
                    Fact.push_back(j);
                }
                else
                {
                    Fact.push_back(j);
                    Fact.push_back(A[i]/j);
                }
            }
        }
        int ans=DP[i-1]+1;
        for(j=0;j<Fact.size();j++)
        {
            if(M.find(Fact[j])==M.end())
            {
                M[Fact[j]]=DP[i-1];
            }
            else
            {
                ans=min(ans,M[Fact[j]]+1);
            }
        }
        DP[i]=ans;
    }
    cout<<DP[n]<<endl;
}
int32_t main()
{
    boost;
    int  t=1;
    // cin>>t;
    for(int i=1;i<=t;i++)
    {
        //cout<<"Case #"<<i<<": ";
        solve();
    }
}
```

Time Complexity: N*Sqrt(max(A[i]))
P.S There can be a optimization of calculation of factor using the sieve instead of calculating factor every time for every number.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    vector<int>a(n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    vector<int>dp(n+1,0);
    dp[n-1]=1;
    for(int i=n-2;i>=0;i--){
        dp[i]=1+dp[i+1];
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++){
            if(__gcd(a[i],a[j])>1)
                dp[i]=min(dp[i],1+dp[j+1]);
        }
    }
    cout<<dp[0];
    return 0;
}
```